# news server application using database in java (networking concepts)

Tags: java, applet, database-connection

Client should connect to the server using ip address and port number.server should display the news in the format serial number, date, ,headlines.client should get the detailed news by clicking on required headline. Server should also provide client with upload option.client by choosing upload option should enter 4 digit passcode.if the entered passcode is correct then server should ask client for headlines and body of the news.by clicking on post option the uploaded  new s should be get updated in the server's database immediately which should be displayed to the client who has entered next.i am not aware of code for upload option and update it in the database. I am newbie. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What language you use for the front end part of your application.
For access the database you can use Java Persistence API or JDBC API.
I need more info what database you use.Are you using ejb.

Comment: For frond end-java and database-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I will show you steps for access you database using JDBC API.

1. Download JDBC Driver :JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J) from this location http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/
   2.You must put the file mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar in your CLASSPATH variable or copy
   the file in WEB-INF/lib directory of your project.
   3.Connect to database
   There are two approaches using DriverManager class or DataSource class

code section for DriverManager

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/database-name","user","password");
```

code section for DataSource this is preferred way to access database
First you must configure DataSource in your server.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();

DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/registeredname");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();

Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
```

//Executes the given SQL statement, which returns a single ResultSet object.

```
ResultSet rs = executeQuery(String sql);
```

//Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement or //an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as an SQL DDL statement.

```
int result = stat.executeUpdate(String sql);
```

Get Data from ResultSet

```
while(rs.next()){
//There is many methods.You have to read documentation
}
```

Don't forget to close the connection

```
conn.close();
```

VERY IMPORTANT

This is basic code It is incomplete and it is bad programming style.I just want to show the basics. For more information read java API documentation.There is a good tutorial.

Java Server Pages is old front end technology.The new technology is Java Server Faces

This is link to one JSF framework http://www.primefaces.org/

What application server you using.If you tell mi i can help you to configure DataSource